# How to use gsutil to write a query to table?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, gsutil

I am currently using python and pandas to build a query, turn the results into a pandas `dataframe`, and then writing that `dataframe` back to a table. To skip the download and upload step I think I should just execute a query using `gsutil` and direct it to write the results to a table.

The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT id, weight, net_weight
FROM `body_table-1345.bodies.weights
WHERE birthdate >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
```

and I'd like to write the results to the table named `body_table-1345.bodies.eligible`.

My current code uses `pandas.DataFrame.read_gbq` and `pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq` but it takes way too long and I think it's wrong to do it this way. Once I have the correct thing to execute in the command line (using `gsutil`) I will wrap it in `python` code and execute it using `os.system`.

How can I tell `gsutil` to auto-detect the SCHEMA and send the results to a table?

Comment: I recommend using Willian Fuks solution and, also, just to make things clear, `gsutil` is used for GCS and for BigQuery `bq` is used ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Python as a wrapper for the `os` command I'd recommend using the official [Google Cloud Python API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/bigquery). You can perform all these steps quite easily, something like:

```
import google.cloud.bigquery as bq
client = bq.Client.from_service_account_json('path/to/credentials.json')

table = client.dataset("bodies").table("eligible")

query_config = bq.QueryJobConfig()
query_config.destination = table
query = """
    SELECT id, weight, net_weight
    FROM `body_table-1345.bodies.weights
    WHERE birthdate >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
    """
job = client.query(query, job_config=query_config)
```

You'll find in the [official docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/) several other examples of how to do these sorts of operations using the API.